# ScrapySharp causes Windows Form to freeze without exception

Tags: c#, winforms, scrapysharp

When included in my code

```
ScrapingBrowser browser = new ScrapingBrowser();

WebPage testPage = browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("https://www.google.co.uk/"));
```

causes the Windows Form to stop working (once this line is reached in execution, the form freezes and I have to halt execution). However, there are no errors or anything else to indicate something is wrong.

Comment: What is ScrapySharp and why is this tagged html-agility-pack?

Comment: ScrapySharp is a NugetPackage that wraps html-agility-pack. It does not have its own tag on Stackoverflow

Comment: OK, so why is it important here? Your code sample has neither of both.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought the browser control itself had a `NavigateToPage`.

Comment: "WebPage" and "NavigateToPage" are part of ScrapySharp and browser refers to a "ScrapingBrowser"

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/1137827/why-cant-i-us-scrapysharp-in-a-windows-form) might be useful.

Comment: You may want to actually include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You should not use this method from your UI thread. Use your favorite technology ([BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx), [Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx)) to run this on another thread that does not block the UI thread.

You could also use ScrapySharp's own async method:  [NavigateToPageAsync](https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/src/ef610454e2cd037a69e8222d794940d71dd1a4a9/ScrapySharpAsync/Network/ScrapingBrowser.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ScrapingBrowser.cs-358)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that ScrappySharp doesn't work in Windows Forms. I've used the same Form code in a Console project and it works perfectly.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem...i would put it as a comment not as an answer